# postgres: sum if count distinct id = 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I sum total with distinct id and avoid adding total twice?

table:

```
id | total | quantity |
-----------------------
1  | 50    | 1        |
1  | 50    | 2        |
```

expected result:

```
 sum of total | sum of quantity |
---------------------------------
 50           | 3               |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
select id, sum(distinct total), sum(quantity)
from t
group by id;
```

That said, something is wrong with your data when you need `sum(distinct)`. I have never used it in "real" code; only for a demonstration such as this.  Often it means that the data is the result of a query and the aggregation should have been a little different.  Or that there is another `id` that is missing from the data (separate from the value being added up).

Comment: noob question but how does it know to distinct the total according to the id and not distinct it to the same total value? meaning read total(50,50) and id(1,1) instead of total (50, 50) and id (1,2)